# Dockerise Spring Boot to connect to local Postgres database using Docker Compose file. Fatal: Database does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.5, Java 17 and Maven.

It’s my first time trying to dockerise a Spring boot application which also uses a Postgres database, so I’m trying to how to this with docker compose, even though Docker is not really something I'm very experienced with. I went through some tutorials and this is what I have:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: desafio_stone_docker
    container_name: db
```

`application-dev.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/desafio_stone_docker
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/desafio_stone_docker
    username: postgres
    password:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: false
```

I have docker running and I can see the parameters as configured, which can be seen below:

[image]

PS: I don't have a Dockerfile as I understand this is not needed for the newer versions of Spring Boot when working with Docker compose.

Once I have both my docker-compose and application running through IntelliJ, I get an error saying my database does not exist.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "desafio_stone_docker" does not exist.
```

I  believe this is probably caused by connection issues between the host and my docker machine as IntelliJ may be talking to the host only, but I’m not sure what I’m missing to have this fixed. It’s probably something obvious, but I've tried a lot and I really don't know.

PS: I'm trying to do this taking as a basis this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Gdb-jK3Sr4

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

I went through this [other tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS1GwdIfk0c&t=15s) from the same Spring advocate and tried to remove the properties  from my yml files, leaving everything up to docker compose to manage. However, I still get the very same error.

`pom.xml`

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

`compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: desafio_stone_docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration should be `url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/desafio_stone_docker`. I assume your computer was unable to resolve the domain `db`.

Comment: I initially tried with localhost, but I get the same error. Seeing other tutorials, I then changed it to db.

Comment: It is strange. As far as I know, if you are running your Spring Boot app within Docker Compose, you can use `db` as the host. Docker Compose is able to resolve the service name `db`. Alternatively, you can configure `/etc/hosts` to resolve `db` to localhost.

Comment: I think the issue comes from your IntelliJ since it is quite common to run a container like you have configured. Please check your IntelliJ configuration again. Refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker-compose.html

Comment: Intellij is able to run the docker compose file. However, I think the issue may perhaps be on how I'm running the application. I'm running the compose file, then pressing the run button from IntelliJ, but perhaps I should be doing something else, not sure.